# Changing values within a function

Tags: r, function

I have the following function which works fine:

```
d16<-function(x) {
  delay<-difftime(tail(x$date.time[x$station == "L4"],1),
              x$date.time[x$station == "L4"][1],units="mins")

  return (delay)
}
```

I have many functions exactly the same as this however the "L4" changes to a different value e.g. "L5" and so would be:

```
d17<-function(x) {
  delay<-difftime(tail(x$date.time[x$station == "L5"],1),
              x$date.time[x$station == "L5"][1],units="mins")

  return (delay)
}
```

Is it possible to write this into the code so that it changes automatically, rather than writing the function over and over again

some sample data:

```
structure(list(date.time = structure(c(1365923863, 1365923895, 
1365923931, 1365923950, 1365923965, 1368143290, 1368143310, 1368143370, 
1368164838, 1368165029, 1368165346, 1368165376, 1368165474, 1368165497, 
1368165536, 1368165574, 1368165608, 1368165626, 1368165661, 1368165719, 
1368165736, 1368165858, 1368165923, 1368165952, 1368165991, 1368175156, 
1368175173, 1368175193), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
station = c("L4", "L4", "L4", "L4", "L4", "L5", "L5", 
"L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", 
"L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "R05", "L5", "L5", 
"L5", "L5", "L5"), code = c(10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 
10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 
10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 
10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897, 10897)), .Names = c("date.time", 
"station", "code"), row.names = c(26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 3038L, 
3039L, 3040L, 3059L, 3060L, 3061L, 3062L, 3063L, 3064L, 3065L, 
3066L, 3067L, 3068L, 3069L, 3070L, 3071L, 3072L, 3073L, 3074L, 
3075L, 3076L, 3077L, 3078L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Write a function with two arguments...? Like `d_fun <- function(x,station_val){...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be useful to you, since it looks like you are just taking `difftime`s for each station. You will need to run `install.packages("data.table")` first.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x)
dt[,difftime(date.time[1],date.time[.N],units="mins")[[1]],by=station]
```

The result will be a data.frame/data.table listing stations and delays. By default, the delay column will be named "V1". You can alter the last line to set a custom name:

```
dt[,list(
    delay=difftime(date.time[1],date.time[.N],units="mins")[[1]]
),by=station]
```

Here's an example. With this data...

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(
    date.time=sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2013-05-18"),as.Date("2013-06-02"),1),10),
    station=rep(c("A","B"),5),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

I get this result:

```
   station  delay
1:       A -12960
2:       B   7200
```

Probably your data are already sorted so that delays will always have the same sign, but if not, you can set keys for the data table and the columns will be sorted by them: `setkey(dt,station,date.time)`.

To get the matrix of `difftimes`, you can use the base R function `outer`:

```
firsts <- dt[,date.time[1],by=station][,{names(V1)<-station;V1}]
lasts <- dt[,date.time[.N],by=station][,{names(V1)<-station;V1}]
outer(firsts,lasts,difftime,units="mins")
```

which gives

```
       A    B
A -12960 5760
B -11520 7200
```

Unfortunately, `difftime` gives weird output, so to get this information in a well-behaved `data.frame`, we'll need to roll a new function:

```
my_difftime <- Vectorize(function(x,y)difftime(x,y,units="mins")[[1]])
diffs <- as.data.frame(outer(firsts,lasts,my_difftime))
```

With the (newly posted) sample data, we get

```
          L4          L5         R05
L4     -1.70 -37522.1667 -37367.6667
L5  36988.75   -531.7167   -377.2167
R05 37365.97   -154.5000      0.0000
```

Each entry in this matrix shows the `difftime` between the first observation of the row station and the last observation of the column station.

Comment: yes this works fine, havent seen that before, however i am not always looking at delay i also look at difftime between two different stations and so the values in the original function may not be same:'tm1<-function(x) {
  delay<-difftime(x$date.time[x$station == "M2"][1],
                  tail(x$date.time[x$station == "M1"],1,units="mins"))
  return (delay)
}'

Comment: Ah, in that case, you will want to use the method described by Ricardo, and extend it to have three arguments: `function(x, station1, station2=station1)`. This will allow you to continue using a single function. When you pass nothing for station2, it will automatically take station1=station2.

Comment: @Salmosalar Ok, I've edited my answer to address all pairs of stations.

Comment: I see how this works, nice!! however i cant seem to get the output into a dataframe? also i was initially running the code across a list using sapply, again struggling to get your answer into a function as such to do this....realise i have ended up raising more questions. Have edited original and put in example data

Comment: @Salmosalar Yeah, I didn't realize that the `outer` output was so weird. I've added another idea at the end.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are simply asking how to include a variable argument in a function.

The solution is to:

- Step 1: include a variable inside `function(...)`
- Step 2: replace the value with in the function with the variable
- Step 3: when you call the function, supply the appropriate value

For example:

```
d <- function (x,  var) { 
###                 ^^^    Variable incliuded

  delay<-difftime(tail(x$date.time[x$station == var],1),
###         replace the value with variable name ^^^   

              x$date.time[x$station == var][1],units="mins")
###  ... everywhere the value appears   ^^^^

  return (delay)
}
```

now when you call the function:

```
d(x, "L5")
d(x, "L4")
...
etc
```

---

You can use as many variables as are needed.  eg:

```
d <- function (x,  var1, var2) 
  {  ..<do something with var1 and var2>.. }
```

You can give any variable a default value.  When you call the function, if you do not change the value of that variable, it takes on its default.

If you sometimes want `var2` & `var1` to have the same value, but sometimes want them to be different values, then Frank's recommedation (in the comments above) is spot on, which is to give set `var2`'s default
value to be the value of `var1`.

```
d <- function (x,  var1, var2=var1) 
  {  ..<do something with var1 and var2>.. }
```

(Note that `R` does not evaluate (check for) the value of each variable until it is actually used, which is why this works, but also, make sure not to change the value of `var1` within the function before evaluating `var2`)

Comment: Maybe you can extend your answer to cover the case the OP commented above (different stations). By the way, you say "val" instead of "var" once.

Comment: Yes i know about this, but doesnt get around calling upto 100 functions which are almost exactly the same

Comment: @Salmosalar, if you know about this already, then what is the issue?  What are you trying to accomplish that you cannot?

Comment: @Salmosalar It looks like Ricardo is proposing that you use one function -- your own version of `d` -- and iterate or `*apply` (`sapply`,`lapply`,...) it over your ~100 function arguments.